# Form call with AJAX

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony

I have a problem when I try to send a form with ajax.

My twig :

```twig
<div class="admin_creation"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.admin_creation').ready(
    function () {
        var id = {{ elem.id }}
        $.ajax({
            data:'id='+id,
            url: Routing.generate('creation_update'),
            success: function(response){
                console.log('ok');
                $('.admin_creation').prepend(response);
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('fail');
            }
        });
    })

</script>
```

my route:

```yaml
creation_update:
    path: /detail/update
    defaults: { _controller: NemiTwigBundle:Default:update }
    options:
        expose: true
```

my controller:

```php
public function updateAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $id = $request->query->get('id');
    $creation = $em->getRepository('NemiTwigBundle:Creation')->findOneById($id);

    //at this point, if i print_r($creation), there is nothing. The $id is correct.
    //when i print($creation), the __tostring method is working and display the right
    //name of the creation.


    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()->add('price', 'integer')
                                      ->add('submit', 'submit')
                                      ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $creation->setPrice($form['price']->getData());
        $em->persist($creation);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('creation_detail', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return $this->render('NemiTwigBundle::creation_update_form.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

the form :

```twig
<form action="{{ path('creation_update') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST">
    {{ form(form) }}
</form>
```

My actual problem is that my id in controller is the right id, there is creation entity with this id but when I try to load this creation with doctrine, it's not working (I think it's not working with private attributes and methods cause when I try to `print($creation)`, the `__toString` method is work fine and give the right result).

**edit : For the first answer,**

i tried with this controller as you suggest :

```twig
public function updateAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $id = $request->query->get('id');
    $creation = $em->getRepository('NemiTwigBundle:Creation')->findOneById($id);

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($creation)->add('price', 'integer')
                                      ->add('submit', 'submit')
                                      ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $em->persist($creation);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('creation_detail', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return $this->render('NemiTwigBundle::creation_update_form.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
```

but i got this error :

Expected argument of type "string, Symfony\Component\Form\ResolvedFormTypeInterface or Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface", "Nemi\TwigBundle\Entity\Creation" given

Comment: $this->createFormBuilder($creation)->...?

apart from that I'm not really sure what you mean. You try to save the entity but when you load it the saved data isn't there?

Comment: hello, i am trying to update an existing creation. So the creation exists and i try to update the price. But when i try to load the entity with findById(), i cannot print_r it (to check if it's working). But when i try to access a public attribute or method, it's working so it's weird. I will update my question with more details

Comment: @hadesMM why not pass an id to the update action? Also while you're updating the entity there is no need to persist it I think.

Comment: it's an ajax request, i have to pass the id like i did, and i need to persist the item to save it in the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($creation)->add('price', 'integer')
                                      ->add('submit', 'submit')
                                      ->getForm();
```

The thing is that you currently create the form without the entity.

What you are basically doing is

1. load the entity
2. Create the Form
3. put the variables in the request into the form
4. save the entity.

You are not adding the entity to the form.
If you create the form with the loaded entity, it adds the changed values to the entity.

Comment: Hello, thx for your answer, i tried like you said but it still not working, i may fail something :/ ps: i have edit my question with the new controller)